# Adding columns to a Spark dataframe conditionally

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, multiple-columns

I have a Spark dataframe like the one below:

[image]

Also, another dataframe:

[image]

The output that I expect is below. I need two columns to be added conditionally to the original data dataframe where:
"offeramount1" = 75% of (amount)
"offeramount2" = 65% of (amount)

This offer is only to be given when the code is not in the "exclusioncode"

[image]

I am able to add the columns without any issues using `withColumn`, but I'm unable to compare the data frames properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do two joins - `'leftanti'` and `'right'`:

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('c1', 10), ('c2', 12), ('c3', 14), ('c4', 16), ('c5', 18), ('c6', 20), ('c7', 22), ('c8', 24), ('c9', 26), ('c10', 28)], ['codes', 'amount'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('c3',), ('c4',), ('c9',)], ['exclusioncode'])
```

Script:

```py
df = (df1
    .join(df2, df1.codes == df2.exclusioncode, 'leftanti')
    .withColumn('offeramount1', F.round(F.col('amount') * .75, 1))
    .withColumn('offeramount2', F.round(F.col('amount') * .65, 1))
    .join(df1, ['codes', 'amount'], 'right')
)
df.show()
# +-----+------+------------+------------+
# |codes|amount|offeramount1|offeramount2|
# +-----+------+------------+------------+
# |   c3|    14|        null|        null|
# |   c1|    10|         7.5|         6.5|
# |   c4|    16|        null|        null|
# |   c5|    18|        13.5|        11.7|
# |   c2|    12|         9.0|         7.8|
# |   c6|    20|        15.0|        13.0|
# |  c10|    28|        21.0|        18.2|
# |   c8|    24|        18.0|        15.6|
# |   c7|    22|        16.5|        14.3|
# |   c9|    26|        null|        null|
# +-----+------+------------+------------+
```

You cannot fill null values with "no offer", as columns in Spark contain only one data type. "no offer" would be a *string* while other values are numeric, hence two separate data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join and a when condition (I'll call `amount_df` the `DataFrame` with the amounts for each code, while `exclusion_code_df` the `DataFrame` with the codes to be excluded):

```py
offer_df = (
    amount_df
    .join(exclusion_code_df, F.col('codes') == F.col('exclusioncode'), how='left')
    .withColumn('offeramount1', F.when(F.col('exclusioncode').isNull(), 0.75 * F.col('amount')).otherwise('no offer'))
    .withColumn('offeramount2', F.when(F.col('exclusioncode').isNull(), 0.65 * F.col('amount')).otherwise('no offer'))
    .drop('exclusioncode')
)
```

`offer_df` is the following `DataFrame`:

```bash
+-----+------+------------+------------------+
|codes|amount|offeramount1|offeramount2      |
+-----+------+------------+------------------+
|c1   |10    |7.5         |6.5               |
|c10  |28    |21.0        |18.2              |
|c2   |12    |9.0         |7.800000000000001 |
|c3   |14    |no offer    |no offer          |
|c4   |16    |no offer    |no offer          |
|c5   |18    |13.5        |11.700000000000001|
|c6   |20    |15.0        |13.0              |
|c7   |22    |16.5        |14.3              |
|c8   |24    |18.0        |15.600000000000001|
|c9   |26    |no offer    |no offer          |
+-----+------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: This works thanks a lot for helping me with this code snippet.